# Avoid multiple Radio Button selection in Java(Netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans

I can't seem to correct this. I have two radio buttons in GUI and I can't select only one while the other one is not selected.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();  
    group.add(jRadioButton1); 
    group.add(jRadioButton2); 

    if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()){
        jLabel1.setText("1");
    }

    else if(jRadioButton2.isSelected()){
        jLabel1.setText("2");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem the you are facing ? The topic and the question are both conflicting.

Comment: Create and populate the ButtonGroup exactly once, in the same block of code that constructs the JRadioButtons.  The whole point of a ButtonGroup is to enforce the one-of-many selection policy you want, so you need to do it before showing your user interface.

Comment: You don't want to have your button group declared in the ActionListener because that means its only being created on a button click. Move the group and assignments outside of there and try again.